# ¿Cómo hacer operaciones con dataFrames en Python y Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo un dataFrame llamado 'ista_produccion_Terminado_Embolsado.csv' con los siguientes datos

```
,planta,fecha,linea,turno,producto,cajas,lbs,resto,velocidad,tipo
0,P3,2018-01-02,P3 EMB. AUTOMATICO 1,T2,BROCCOLI FLORETS 12/32  OZ SIMPLOT CLASSIC  ,303.0,7272.0,0.0,34.0,TERMINADO
1,P1,2018-01-02,P1 EMB. AUTOMATICO 2,T2,BROCCOLI FLORETS 12/32  OZ JACK IN THE BOX  ,76.0,1824.0,0.0,,TERMINADO
2,P1,2018-01-02,P1 EMB. AUTOMATICO 8,T2,BROCCOLI CUTS 12/16 OZ ESSENTIAL EVERY DAY  ,378.0,4536.0,0.0,33.0,TERMINADO
3,P1,2018-01-02,P1 EMB. AUTOMATICO 4,T2,BROCCOLI FLORETS 12/32  OZ MONARCH PETITE,154.0,3696.0,0.0,25.0,TERMINADO
4,P3,2018-01-02,P3 EMB. AUTOMATICO 11,T2,CAULIFLOWER FLORETS 8/12 OZ WEDGE STEAM BOTTOM GU,1253.0,7518.0,0.0,50.0,TERMINADO
5,P3,2018-01-02,P3 EMB. AUTOMATICO 6,T2,BROCCOLI ORGANIC FLORETS 12/16 OZ 365 ORGANIC  ,167.0,2004.0,0.0,,TERMINADO
```

de este archivo el primer dato que quiero obtener es la suma de la columna 'lbs' agrupada por planta

```
prod_planta = lista_produccion_terminado_embolsado.reset_index().groupby(['planta'])['lbs'].sum()
```

posteriormente quiero obtener el dato de la producción 'lbs' agrupada por 'planta' y por 'línea':

```
prod_linea = lista_produccion_terminado_embolsado.reset_index().groupby(['planta','linea'])['lbs'].sum()
```

Ahora que ya tengo estas dos series pd.prod_planta y pd Prod_linea ¿Cómo le hago para obtener el porcentaje de la producción por línea y que en el mismo dataFrame me aparezcan las producción 'lbs' de cada línea y su porcentaje?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres agregar las columnas a tu dataframe original la base ya la tienes al crear ambas series, puedes conseguirlo usando [`pandas.DataFrame.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) para crear las columnas:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO


data = StringIO('''
,planta,fecha,linea,turno,producto,cajas,lbs,resto,velocidad,tipo
0,P3,2018-01-02,P3 EMB. AUTOMATICO 1,T2,BROCCOLI FLORETS 12/32  OZ SIMPLOT CLASSIC  ,303.0,7272.0,0.0,34.0,TERMINADO
1,P1,2018-01-02,P1 EMB. AUTOMATICO 2,T2,BROCCOLI FLORETS 12/32  OZ JACK IN THE BOX  ,76.0,1824.0,0.0,,TERMINADO
2,P1,2018-01-02,P1 EMB. AUTOMATICO 8,T2,BROCCOLI CUTS 12/16 OZ ESSENTIAL EVERY DAY  ,378.0,4536.0,0.0,33.0,TERMINADO
3,P1,2018-01-02,P1 EMB. AUTOMATICO 4,T2,BROCCOLI FLORETS 12/32  OZ MONARCH PETITE,154.0,3696.0,0.0,25.0,TERMINADO
4,P3,2018-01-02,P3 EMB. AUTOMATICO 11,T2,CAULIFLOWER FLORETS 8/12 OZ WEDGE STEAM BOTTOM GU,1253.0,7518.0,0.0,50.0,TERMINADO
5,P3,2018-01-02,P3 EMB. AUTOMATICO 6,T2,BROCCOLI ORGANIC FLORETS 12/16 OZ 365 ORGANIC  ,167.0,2004.0,0.0,,TERMINADO
6,P3,2018-01-02,P3 EMB. AUTOMATICO 6,T2,BROCCOLI ORGANIC FLORETS 12/16 OZ 365 ORGANIC  ,167.0,4521.0,0.0,,TERMINADO

''')

df = pd.read_csv(data, index_col=0)
df['prod_linea'] = df.groupby(['planta', 'linea']).transform(sum)['lbs']
df['prod_linea_%'] = df['prod_linea'] / df.groupby(['planta']).transform(sum)['lbs'] * 100
```

La salida es:

```
>>> df
  planta       fecha                  linea turno  \
0     P3  2018-01-02   P3 EMB. AUTOMATICO 1    T2   
1     P1  2018-01-02   P1 EMB. AUTOMATICO 2    T2   
2     P1  2018-01-02   P1 EMB. AUTOMATICO 8    T2   
3     P1  2018-01-02   P1 EMB. AUTOMATICO 4    T2   
4     P3  2018-01-02  P3 EMB. AUTOMATICO 11    T2   
5     P3  2018-01-02   P3 EMB. AUTOMATICO 6    T2   
6     P3  2018-01-02   P3 EMB. AUTOMATICO 6    T2   

                                            producto   cajas     lbs  resto  \
0       BROCCOLI FLORETS 12/32  OZ SIMPLOT CLASSIC     303.0  7272.0    0.0   
1       BROCCOLI FLORETS 12/32  OZ JACK IN THE BOX      76.0  1824.0    0.0   
2       BROCCOLI CUTS 12/16 OZ ESSENTIAL EVERY DAY     378.0  4536.0    0.0   
3          BROCCOLI FLORETS 12/32  OZ MONARCH PETITE   154.0  3696.0    0.0   
4  CAULIFLOWER FLORETS 8/12 OZ WEDGE STEAM BOTTOM GU  1253.0  7518.0    0.0   
5    BROCCOLI ORGANIC FLORETS 12/16 OZ 365 ORGANIC     167.0  2004.0    0.0   
6    BROCCOLI ORGANIC FLORETS 12/16 OZ 365 ORGANIC     167.0  4521.0    0.0   

   velocidad       tipo prod_linea prod_linea_%  
0       34.0  TERMINADO       7272      34.1168  
1        NaN  TERMINADO       1824      18.1384  
2       33.0  TERMINADO       4536      45.1074  
3       25.0  TERMINADO       3696      36.7542  
4       50.0  TERMINADO       7518      35.2709  
5        NaN  TERMINADO       6525      30.6122  
6        NaN  TERMINADO       6525      30.6122
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, la función pandas.DataFrame.transform me ha sido de gran utilidad.